# Multi-form in the SAME page - creating MARKER with input ADDRESS and store in DATABASE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, google-maps

I'm trying to create a form to create an event which will be stored in a database.
To do so, I chose to have **a form to give the place** of the event and **another one to describe the event**, both on the **same page** with JQuery.

My problem is to **get the coordinates** of the address input by the user to create a map with a marker at the end of the form, and then store this into the database. **The problem may come from the moments my functions are called or something like that.**
The marker which should be generated from the address input isn't showing on the map of the step n°2 (actually the third, which should be a recap of the event being created), then when I validate this step, there is a message saying that the lat and lng are not retrieved (should be by $_GET variable).

I've never practised Javascript (I got a template that I adaptated for this form) and I'm a bit tired of trying various hazardous solutions to fetch the coordinates, could someone help me ? Here's the main code of my page (yes, it's partly in french) :

```
<body class="nighty-background-purple">
<!--les formulaires html-->
<div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div id="head"><!-- Head -->
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
                <h1>Créez votre Night !</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Head -->
        <div id="etape_simulation"><!-- Etape simulation -->
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="progression">
                        <li class="firstcircle"><span class="numberCircle">1</span><span class="normal">La Night</span></li>
                        <li><span class="numberCircle">2</span><span class="normal">Le lieu</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="row"><!-- Row -->
                    <form id="step1" method="post" name="step1" action="?step=1"><!-- Step 1 : Lieu -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div><!-- Nom du Lieu -->
                                    <label for="nomL" class="control-label">Nom du lieu</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="nomL" name="nomL" />
                                </div><!-- Nom du Lieu -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div><!-- Adresse -->
                                    <label for="address" class="control-label">Adresse</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" required/>
                                </div><!-- Adresse -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div><!-- Code Postal -->
                                    <label for="codePostalL" class="control-label">Code Postal</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="codePostalL" class="form-control" name="codePostalL" required />
                                </div><!-- Code Postal -->
                                <div><!-- Ville -->
                                    <label for="villeL" class="control-label">Ville</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="villeL" class="form-control" name="villeL" required />
                                </div><!-- Ville -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group"><!-- Type de Lieu -->
                            <label for="typeL" class="control-label">Type de lieu</label>
                            <br/>
                            <select class="form-control"  id="typeL" name="typeL">
                                <option value="Maison">Maison</option>
                                <option value="Appartement">Appartement</option>
                                <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                                <option value="Boîte de nuit" >Boîte de nuit</option>
                                <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
                                <option value="Salle">Salle</option>
                                <option value="Parc">Parc</option>
                                <option value="Autre">Autre...</option>
                            </select>
                        </div><!-- Type de Lieu -->
                        <div class="form-group"><!-- Etape suivante -->
                            <button class="greenbutton btn-lg" type="submit" id="creationL" >Étape suivante</button>
                        </div><!-- Etape suivante -->
                    </form><!-- Step 1 : Lieu -->

                    <form id="step2" method="post" name="step2" action="?step=2" style="display: none"><!-- Step 2 : Événement -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div><!-- Nom événement -->
                                    <label for="nomE" class="control-label">Nom de votre Night</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomE" id="nomE" required/>
                                </div><!-- Nom événement -->
                                <div><!-- Date Heure Début -->
                                    <label for="dateHeureDebut" class="control-label">Date et heure de début :</label>
                                    <input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="dateHeureDebut" id="dateHeureDebut" placeholder="01-01-2018 20:00" required/>
                                </div><!-- Date Heure Début -->
                                <div><!-- Date Heure Fin -->
                                    <label for="dateHeureFin" class="control-label">Date et heure de fin :</label>
                                    <input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="dateHeureFin" id="dateHeureFin" placeholder="01-01-2018 20:00" />
                                </div><!-- Date Heure Fin -->
                                <div><!-- Description -->
                                    <label for="descriptionE" class="control-label">Description</label>
                                    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="form-control" name="descriptionE" id="descriptionE" required></textarea>
                                </div><!-- Description -->
                                <div><!-- Capacité -->
                                    <label for="capaciteE" class="control-label">Capacité (en personnes)</label>
                                    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="capaciteE" id="capaciteE" required />
                                </div><!-- Capacité -->
                                <div><!-- Type événement -->
                                    <label for="typeE" class="control-label">Type d'événement</label>
                                    <select class="form-control"  id="typeE" name="typeE">
                                        <option value="01">Soirée entre amis</option>
                                        <option value="02">Fête</option>
                                        <option value="03">Pot</option>
                                        <option value="04" >Cocktail</option>
                                        <option value="05">Dîner</option>
                                        <option value="06">Apéro</option>
                                        <option value="07">Night club</option>
                                        <option value="08">Autre...</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div><!-- Type événement -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="row"><!-- Créer Night -->
                                <button class="greenbutton btn-lg" type="submit" id="creationE" >Créer ma Night !!</button>
                            </div><!-- Créer Night -->
                        </div><!-- form-group -->
                    </form><!-- Step 2 : Événement -->

                    <form id="step3" method="post" name="step3" action="?step=3" style="display: none"><!-- Step 3 : Confirmation -->
                        <h2>Récapitulatif de votre Night</h2>
                        <div class="row" id="map">

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="validerE">Valider cette Night</button>
                        </div>
                    </form><!-- Step 3 : Confirmation -->
                </div><!-- Row -->
            </div><!-- Col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 -->
        </div><!-- Etape simulation -->
    </main>
</div>
<?php require('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Nighty/footer/footer.php') ?>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.852922, 2.349846),
            zoom: 12
        });

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        document.getElementById('creationE').addEventListener('click', function() {
            geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
        var lat = geocodeAddress().latitude;
        lat = encodeURIComponent(lat);
        var lng = geocodeAddress().longitude;
        lng = encodeURIComponent(lng);
        window.location.href="nightCreation.php?step=2&lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng;
        /*Don't know where to put this*/
    }

    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: resultsMap,
                 position: results[0].geometry.location
                 });
            } else {
                alert('Adresse incorrecte, veuillez la préciser ou la corriger.');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=NOT_REVEALING_MY_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Can you describe what you expect to happen, and what happens instead?  Does your code generate any errors?

Comment: I edited my post. I'm not sure my PHP code would be useful here, it's mainly getting inputs into SESSION to send them into the database at the end.